# how to change the rows and columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

i have code like this which creates dataframe from the dictionary, but the output is differant from what is expected. Have given the code as follows with steps

```
options_pnl={'BTC': {'Pnl(since 6pm)': Decimal('7831.52228528'),
  'Pnl(4 hr)': Decimal('2930.47450133'),
  'Pnl(1 hr)': Decimal('1416.81306308'),
  'Volume(since 6pm)': Decimal('24509290.62181862'),
  'Volume(4 hr)': Decimal('4504202.83422724'),
  'Volume(1 hr)': Decimal('1067850.01837278')},
 'ETH': {'Pnl(since 6pm)': Decimal('387.87564823'),
  'Pnl(4 hr)': Decimal('-349.14871930'),
  'Pnl(1 hr)': Decimal('656.74824550'),
  'Volume(since 6pm)': Decimal('10700784.53262117'),
  'Volume(4 hr)': Decimal('1968872.36761706'),
  'Volume(1 hr)': Decimal('778937.22275036')}}
options_pnl_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(options_pnl)
options_pnl_df = options_pnl_df.astype('int64')
options_pnl_df = options_pnl_df.transpose()
display(options_pnl_df)
```

and output is like below :

```
     Pnl(since 6pm) Pnl(4 hr)   Pnl(1 hr)   Volume(since 6pm)   Volume(4 hr)    Volume(1 hr)
BTC  7831   2930    1416    24509290    4504202 1067850
ETH  387    -349    656 10700784    1968872 778937
```

I need to change the structure to this from the above ouput to the below output given

```
                         PNL    Volume
BTC since 6pm       7831       24509290
BTC since last 4 hr 2930       4504202
BTC last 1 hr       1416       1067850
ETH since 6pm       387        10700784
ETH since last 4 hr -349       1968872  
ETH last 1 hr       656        778937
```

tried with

```
data = []

for asset, values in options_pnl.items():
    for interval, metrics in values.items():
        metric_type, metric_interval = interval.split('(')
        metric_interval = metric_interval.rstrip(')')  # remove trailing ')'
        pnl_value = metrics if metric_type == 'Pnl' else 0
        volume_value = metrics if metric_type == 'Volume' else 0
        data.append([asset, metric_interval, pnl_value, volume_value])

columns = ['Asset', 'Type', 'PNL', 'Volume']
options_pnl_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

print(options_pnl_df)
```

but not getting desired ouput, could someone make the desired output from the given dicts

Comment: yes but output is differant for that also, can use whatever code needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the current column index to a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) and then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the result:

```py
options_pnl_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(options_pnl_df
                             .columns.str.extract(r'(\w+)\s*\(([\w\s]+)', expand=True)
                             .T
                             .values
                         )
options_pnl_df = options_pnl_df.stack()
```

Output:

```
                Pnl    Volume
BTC 1 hr       1416   1067850
    4 hr       2930   4504202
    since 6pm  7831  24509290
ETH 1 hr        656    778937
    4 hr       -349   1968872
    since 6pm   387  10700784
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have two categories (BTC and ETH) and want to use the same time intervals to create indexes. Here's one way to solve it.

```py
index_list = []
options_pnl_dict = {}
for category, values in options_pnl.items():
  for k,v in values.items():
    temp = k.split("(")
    index = f"{category} ({temp[1].strip()[:-1]})"
    if index not in index_list:
      index_list.append(index)
    
    if temp[0] in options_pnl_dict.keys():
      options_pnl_dict[temp[0]].append(v)
    else:  
      options_pnl_dict[temp[0]] = [v]
```

Now you have the index and the dictionary.

```py
pd.DataFrame(options_pnl_dict, index=index_list)
```

```
                                 PNL             Volume
BTC (since 6pm)        7831.52228528  24509290.62181862
BTC (since last 4 hr)  2930.47450133   4504202.83422724
BTC (last 1 hr)        1416.81306308   1067850.01837278
ETH (since 6pm)         387.87564823  10700784.53262117
ETH (since last 4 hr)  -349.14871930   1968872.36761706
ETH (last 1 hr)         656.74824550    778937.22275036
```

Comment: ok but can you make the options_pnl dict same as what i have mentioned

Comment: also the category and time interval from the dict itself, instead of hardcoding.